# call controller action from module.php in zf2 onBootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, module, bootstrapping

i am tracking the api error codes from module.php file. I want to pass the data to controller or want to create an adapter in module.php file.
Please suggest me different ways so that i can track and store error codes from module.php file itself.

i only want to exe a controller action and not want to redirect from module.php

Thanks in advance !

```
     public function handleError(MvcEvent $evt)
     {
        $application  = $evt->getApplication();
        $eventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $eventManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\ApiTrackController', 'dispatch', function($event) {
        $controller = $event->getTarget();

        // Set public property
        $controller->trackapi = 'trackapi';//ActionName
        });//attach ends here.
    }//Handle error function ends.
```

Comment: You can track error by attaching your listener to event manager (dispatch_error).

Comment: public function handleError(MvcEvent $evt)
    {        
         $application  = $evt->getApplication();
         $eventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
         $eventManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\ApiTrackController', 'dispatch', function($event) {
         $controller = $event->getTarget();

            // Set public property
            $controller->trackapi = 'trackapi';
          });

}

i am doing this. tell how can i receive this in targeted controller and also i want to pass some data to this controller. As i am new to ZF2 so getting difficulties.

Comment: Hey venca thanks for the comment.

I have also attached the code snippet to above question. This is how i am attaching to event manager. But tell me how can i receive this event in to that ApiTrackController with some data values.

Comment: Well, I think it is not necessary to pull data to controller. You can track it in your listener directly. Just create your listener, grab it through factory from service manager and attach it in your module to the event manager. I hope I clariefied it little bit.

Comment: thanks venca for the quick response. i will look into that.

Comment: do u have any example for me to refer ?

Comment: Module example https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-rest/blob/master/src/Module.php and listener https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-rest/blob/master/src/Mvc/HttpExceptionListener.php